# Filter data using Advanced Filter then copy to the bottom data in another table

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I am working on a report that will filter data from a table, then copy that data into another sheet, and then delete the rows from the original table. Below is what I have so far, which works, however, I am not sure how to copy the filtered data into another sheet without erasing what was already there. I am new to VBA, so any notes in code would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub International_Filter()
    
    Dim Working As Range, IntULD As Range, Copyto As Range
    
    ' Working is the datatable that tracking numbers will be filtered, copied, and deleted
    ' INTULD is a list of criteria that needs to be filtered
    ' CopyTO is the sheet where the data will be copied

    Set Working = Sheets("Working").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set IntULD = Sheets("OPC Exception").Range("M6").CurrentRegion    
    Set Copyto = Sheets("International").Range("A1").CurrentRegion    
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Working").ShowAllData
    Working.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, IntULD, Copyto
    Working.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, IntULD
    Range("A1").Select
    If Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Address = "$A$1" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If Cells(Columns("A").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row > 2 Then
            Range(selection, Cells(Columns("A").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        End If
        selection.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Working").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? You want to copy data to `Sheets("International").Range("A1")` and you want to preserve all the info on the `Sheets("International").Range("A1")`, so you want to know how to add enough new rows at the very beginning of `Sheets("International").Range("A1")` , right?

Comment: Yes that would work. The goal is to add data to Sheets("International") Column A without copying over the existing data that is in that row.

Comment: You should probably use a line before copying that tells you what's the last row.. like  ` lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row` and then your copy starts from Range("A" & lr) so you do not overwrite what's already there.

Comment: `AdvancedFilter` wasn't built for this case. Several workarounds come to mind. Could you share the contents of `IntULD` (if they're not too complicated, e.g. `AutoFilter` could be used instead)? Also, is this code in the workbook containing these worksheets? BTW, you shouldn't use `On Error Resume Next` so carelessly i.e. without a 'closing' e.g. `On Error Goto 0`.

Answer (score 0):

How to insert filtered data at the beginning of a destination:

```
Sub International_Filter()
    Dim Source As Range       ' Data to look at
    Dim Data As Range         ' Filtered data to copy
    Dim Criteria As Range     ' Criteria for Advanced Filter
    Dim Destination As Range  ' Place to copy filtered data
    Dim Area As Range

    Set Source = Sheets("Working").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set Criteria = Sheets("OPC Exception").Range("M6").CurrentRegion    
    Set Destination = Sheets("International").Range("A1")

    With Source
        .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Criteria
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Data = .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.ShowAllData
        If Data Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        For Each Area In Data.Areas
            Area.Copy
            Destination.Insert xlShiftDown
        Next Area
        Data.Delete xlShiftUp
    End With
End Sub
```

p.s. From my point of view it's better to copy data at the end of existing data. So in this case the last part of the code is:

```
   ...
   With Sheets("International").UsedRange
      Set Destination = .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count)
   End With
   ...
   If Data Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Data.Copy Destination
   Data.Delete xlShiftUp
   ...
```